# Conda: Installing directly from github yields ERROR File "setup.py" not found for legacy project

Tags: python, git, installation, anaconda, setup.py

I am new to Anaconda, Python, etc. I would like to install directly from github until I can figure out a better way to do it.  When downloading the package from github, I get an error.  I proceed as follows:

I open the Anaconda Navigator.  In Navigator, I go to EnvironmentName.  In EnvironmentName, I install CMD.exe Prompt.  I launch.
In CMD.exe Prompt:

```
(EnvironmentName) C:\Users\jmlhe>conda install git pip
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\jmlhe\anaconda3\envs\EnvironmentName

  added / updated specs:
    - git
    - pip


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  git                pkgs/main/win-64::git-2.34.1-haa95532_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? *y*

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(EnvironmentName) C:\Users\jmlhe>pip install git+[https://github.com/Jake0303/Webull-Trading-Bot

Collecting git+https://github.com/Jake0303/Webull-Trading-Bot
  Cloning https://github.com/Jake0303/Webull-Trading-Bot to c:\users\jmlhe\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-kfgodn_t
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/Jake0303/Webull-Trading-Bot 'C:\Users\jmlhe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kfgodn_t'
  Resolved https://github.com/Jake0303/Webull-Trading-Bot to commit f3f195c59ada21b60dcfbe501edec48d13158271
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project git+https://github.com/Jake0303/Webull-Trading-Bot.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That project, https://github.com/Jake0303/Webull-Trading-Bot, can't be installed with `pip`, since it contains neither `pyproject.toml` for PEP 518 builds, nor `setup.py` for legacy builds.

By the looks of it, you're supposed to just grab a clone from Git and work with that.

Comment: Thanks so much!  What would grabbing a clone from Git entail? As I'm new, this is all like a foreign language to me.  I would upvote your post but don't have enough points yet.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm looking through this rn: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: Github also has a great tutorial.